# How to set a range of values in numpy to nan?

Tags: python, numpy

My dataset looks like following:

```
>>> difference
array([[ -1,   0,   4],
       [-20,   2,  -1],
       [  2, -20,   0]])
```

I want values ranging from +2 to -2 to be replace by nan.

the resultant array should look like following.

```
>>> difference 
array([[ nan,  nan,   4.],
       [-20.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan, -20.,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `np.abs(difference)<=2` to get the True values of the range, one way would be with [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), like so -

```
np.where(np.abs(difference)<=2,np.nan,difference)
```

Sample run -

```
In [5]: difference
Out[5]: 
array([[ -1,   0,   4],
       [-20,   2,  -1],
       [  2, -20,   0]])

In [6]: np.where(np.abs(difference)<=2,np.nan,difference)
Out[6]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,   4.],
       [-20.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan, -20.,  nan]])
```

For completeness, a more explicit way to get such a mask would be with `(difference <=2) & (difference >=-2)` instead of `np.abs(difference)<=2`.

Comment: `np.where` is not strictly necessary. You can also use the truth array to index the differences array. eg. `differences[np.abs(differences) <= 2] = np.nan` (provided differences is a float array).

Answer (score 1):

According with float arithmetic, you can do :

```
In [7]: valid =abs(difference)>2

In [8]: valid/valid *difference
Out[8]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,   4.],
       [-20.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan, -20.,  nan]])
```